# Open pdf file from the server in GWT

Tags: gwt

I want to open a pdf file from a button of my GWT application. Actually to access that file I've to query the server that returns the file encoded in base64 from a JSON request.
It's possible to open that file then?

Answer (score 2):

1. To show a pdf "file" (it's not a file, but a byte stream in http reply) you need to rely on browsers own capability to render pdf data. To do this you must either open a URL in a new window or in in an iframe. The second is probably a better option when using GWT. Docs of the GWT [Frame](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.1/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/Frame.html).

   ```
   // url of the pdf (must have application/pdf content-type)
   Frame frame = new Frame("url");  
   // add the frame wherever you want
   RootPanel.get().add(frame);
   ```
2. In order for the browser to correctly display pdf page (by invoking the pdf plugin), the url that serves the pdf data must have a header that says `Content-Type: application/pdf`. Check that your response has this header.

Comment: My request was to be able to display it when I've the pdf byte array in the client from a json query (like a webservice one)

Comment: Look at the headers of your reply - do they contain `Content-Type: application/pdf`?